# Loading blockchain is taking to long for each users in database, any way to make it faster?

Tags: python, blockchain

```
blockchain = pickle.loads(blockchain['blockchain'])
app.logger.debug(f'BlockChain loaded for user {email_to_revoke}. Size: {str(getsizeof(blockchain))} bytes')
previous_block = "0" * 64
try:
    for x, block in enumerate(blockchain):
        if block.index == x and block.previous_block == previous_block:
            response.append((block.data, block.approved_timestamp))
        else:
            if not x == block.index == 0: raise Exception("BLOCKCHAIN_VERIFICATION_ERROR")
        previous_block = block.hash
except Exception as e: app.logger.exception(e)
```

I'm trying to get every user in mongo db to load their blockchain and get specific data, but it's taking forever to load every user data, and my endpoint is going to timeout when I'm sending a request, before it processes every user in db.

Comment: Is it important that the endpoint is synchronous? Could you put the work on a background job?

Comment: Could you comment on why you need to do all these operations in one go? Could you do them when a user signs in, for example?

Comment: I tried to use async but still same enumerate is taking forever for each user, and this is a cronjob so it has to run daily

Comment: How long is "forever" in seconds? Please edit your question with a specific time.

Comment: How many rows of data are you retrieving?

Comment: is not about seconds is about loads blockchain for 9K users, and endpoint is failing because of timeout because before timout is only loading like 40-50 users max

Comment: Is it relevant that you are retrieving blockchain data? It sounds like you are fetching a blob of data per user, and it does not matter what the data contains.

Comment: it depends on users some have many rows some have less depends how many brands it has

Comment: There is a lot of additional context appearing in the comments - please update your question with the additional detail. "Brands" has been introduced as a theme with no context. Currently it is not clear that blockchain is relevant, and ultimately it may just be a MongoDB performance issue. Thus, you'd need to show what calls are creating MongoDB operations, and whether they can be batched up to fetch several things at the same time.